# Truncating table does not make the mysql file smaller

Tags: mysql, truncate, database-administration

I truncated several huge tables, but the mysql file and database appears to remain at the same size.

Does truncate table delete the data from mysql as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a large table is deleted or truncated InnoDB storage engine for MySQL will leave the empty space, and use it for subsequent insertion of new row versions.

There are ways to shrink database. Check [Re: how to shrink a MySQL database](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,121880,121886#msg-121886)

Answer (score 1):

In Version **5.1.55** size was not reduced after **Truncate** , even with **innodb_file_per_table='ON'**. 
So need to **DROP and then CREATE** the table and then **Size was reduced**.