# Is OPTIMIZE / ANALYZE required after mysql table TRUNCATE?

Tags: mysql, truncate

In mysql database, I have about 20 tables (data size is very small - most of the tables have about 1,000 to 20,000 records, only one table has 200,000 records). These tables are being truncated and reloaded fully every day.

Does truncate data every day cause database pages fragmentation?

Should i run analyze and optimize table on them? if so then how often?

Please advise!

Thank you!

Comment: What is your tables engines? After truncate or after truncate + load? I'd definitely analyze table after loading data into it.

Comment: @fifonik, 1) It is Aurora MySQL - uses the InnoDB storage engine. 2) After truncate + load. Even small tables needs to analyzed? and should it be done after every day loads? Thank you!

Comment: Analyze table update statistics that is used for optimizer while choosing indexes. If you select all records from small tables and send it to app then you do not need to actualize statistics. If you are joining these small tables you probably would like to analyze them.

Answer (score 0):

When a table is deleted or truncated, InnoDB will leave the empty space, and use it for subsequent insertion of new row versions.

[Truncating table does not make the mysql file smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870473/truncating-table-does-not-make-the-mysql-file-smaller?rq=1)